# Storm 1.0.2 hdfs-bolt acking tuples when no data is sent to it

Tags: apache, hadoop, apache-storm

I have implemented a Storm topology which takes in JSON data from a Kafka Spout, processes through two bolts and then outputs a message to hdfs using the hdfs-bolt. Using Storm 0.9.6 with Kafka 0.8.2.1 and Hadoop 2.5.0 this worked perfectly. The production system I have implemented this for is updating the tools to Storm 1.0.2, Kakfa 0.10.1.0, and Hadoop 2.6.0. When I updated the package information for the above versions, the hdfs bolt now starts acking "ghost" tuples before I have even sent any data through the spout. It continues to show acks in the UI until the Topology is killed. Furthermore, the messages are only sometimes written to hdfs when I actually process data. Most of the time nothing is output. Any ideas as to what differences in the versions would cause an issue like this?

Comment: Sharing code / code snippet of your implementation will help in understanding problem better for providing any valuable inputs and for others learning.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it is likely that you are facing tick tuples which are emitted to your bolts. Try to add following condition into your execute logic to handle this:

```
public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector oc){      
    if (!TupleUtils.isTick(tuple))
    {
         //Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try that later today. The odd thing is it is only the hdfs bolt and none of the other bolts. Also, I discovered that processing a large number of tuples will force the tuples to be completely processed and for records to be written to hdfs. Sending test files with about 7-20 records doesnt work. I have it set to update the ui and write to hdfs after every tuple. Any insight on that issue?